# FOS/UserBundle: Unrecognized field: usernameCanonical

Tags: php, symfony

I'm very new to Symfony 2.0 and FOS/UserBundle. I'm install it to my project and when I trying to login or register new user I get following errors:

> Unrecognized field: usernameCanonical

I haven't no idea what does it mean? I'm put my codes:

app/config/security.yml file

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: .*
            form-login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path: /login
                use_forward: false
                check_path: /login_check
                failure_path: /not_found
            logout: true
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        # The WDT has to be allowed to anonymous users to avoid requiring the login with the AJAX request
        - { path: ^/_wdt/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/_profiler/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        # AsseticBundle paths used when using the controller for assets
        - { path: ^/js/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/css/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # for the case of a failed login
        - { path: ^/user/new$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/check-confirmation-email$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/confirm/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/confirmed$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/request-reset-password$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/send-resetting-email$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/check-resetting-email$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/reset-password/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: ROLE_USER }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPERADMIN:  ROLE_ADMIN
```

User entity located in SecurityBundle:

```
<?php

namespace App\SecurityBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * App\SecurityBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @orm:Table(name="fos_user")
 * @orm:Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @orm:Id
     * @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @orm:Column(type="string", name="username", length="70")
     */
    protected $username;    

    /**
     * @orm:Column(type="string", name="password", length="70")
     */
    protected $password;    

    /**
     * @orm:Column(type="string", name="email", length="70")
     */
    protected $email;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Please help me?

**EDITED:** When I trying to register new user I get below errors:

```
The "App\SecurityBundle\Entity\User" class metadata does not have any "usernameCanonical" field or association mapping.
```

Added my config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.ini }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    secret:        %secret%
    charset:       UTF-8
    error_handler: null
    csrf_protection:
        enabled: true
    router:        { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
    validation:    { enabled: true, annotations: true }
    templating:    { engines: ['twig'] } #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    session:
        default_locale: %locale%
        lifetime:       3600
        auto_start:     true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        # closure:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/compiler.jar
        # yui_css:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    class:
        model:
            user: App\SecurityBundle\Entity\User

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
                    AppSecurityBundle: { type: annotation, dir: Entity/ }

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%

jms_security_extra:
    secure_controllers:  true
    secure_all_services: false
```

Comment: All metadata for the User ORM mapping is provided in XML format (FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.xml) and your ORM metadata is provided in annotations. I don't think you can use two metatdata formats in the same bundle. Have you found a solution since you posted this question?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the solution? I'm running the lastest versions of both symfony and fosuserbundle and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Zeck Yup, the solution would be nice !

Answer (score 21):

In my case auto mapping doesn't work because I needed to extend entity (not model)

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
```

chage to

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
```

Comment: Using Entity is now [**deprecated**](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Entity/User.php#L23), you should not rely on it.

Comment: yes and no! This answer is correct if you have version "1.3.5" installed. If you are on the -dev branch then @Touki is right.

Comment: It seems like Model is used in version 2.0 whereas Entity is used in 1.3

Answer (score 20):

Maybe Symfony 2 can't read the mapping at all.

At your app/config/config.yml look for the doctrine configuration.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
```

That was all I needed.

Comment: +1 good point on mappings! It started happening the moment I stopped using auto_mapping ;)

Comment: After doing this, I updated the schema: php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force and recreated the admin user: php app/console fos:user:create admintest admin@test.com pass --super-admin. Then it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, in my user class, I was using

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Document\User as BaseUser;
```

instead of

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use the bundle with Symfony2 Beta1 install? The FriendsOfSymfony UserBundle is developed against the bleeding edge repository of Symfony, and if you're using the beta release from [Symfony.com](http://symfony.com), which is quite outdated compared to the current development commit, undoubtedly things will not work as intended with the UserBundle.

You can either wait for a stable release of both Symfony and the FoSUserBundle, or if you're feeling daring, you can keep your working copy up to date with the Symfony GitHub repository found [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony), which will allow you to use the FoSUserBundle in the environment for which it is intended.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to upgrade doctrine/orm and doctrine/doctrine-bundle because for some reason the fields in the base User class were not added to the schema.