# FOS UserBundle -> Unable to create new user

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, extend

This is the very first time I use Symfony2 by myself and I think I've made a mistake when configuring the FOS User Bundle.
Looks like my User entity does not properly extend the FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User.

Here's my User class (basically the same as mentioned on the doc)

```
<?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace VillaPrivee\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Since I use Netbeans, I'm able to "Ctrl click" and make sure "FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User" exists.
So far, I don't see anything wrong...

But when I try to create a new user using my terminal, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method VillaPrivee\UserBundle\Entity\User::setUsername() 
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/VillaPrivee/vendor/friendsofsymfony/
user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Util/UserManipulator.php on line 50
```

Not sure what other details I should provide you guys with, just let me know if any other file could matter in this case.

Thanks for your help!

Edit :

```
<?php

namespace VillaPrivee\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class VillaPriveeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: VillaPrivee\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: is `FOSUserBundle` registered in `AppKernel.php`?

Comment: Could you include `AppKernel.php`? Moreover, why are you extending `FOSUserBundle`? Are you going to manipulate `FOSUserBundle` controllers via override?

Comment: new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),new VillaPrivee\UserBundle\VillaPriveeUserBundle(),

Comment: How am I supposed to include the appKernel? All I did was just following the documentation, I'm not planning on overwriting anything for now

Comment: If you don't need to override something particular, you should remove `return 'FOSUserBundle'` part into `getParent()` method. Moreover with "include AppKernel.php" I mean if you can past it into your question :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you extend wrong class, try with:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
```

**Edit**:

Yep, extending `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User` is deprecated, `Extend FOS\UserBundle\Model\User directly.`
[Documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Entity/User.php#L23)

Comment: doesn't work either... I still get the same error :(

Comment: `code`public function create($username, $password, $email, $active, $superadmin)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setPlainPassword($password);
        $user->setEnabled((Boolean) $active);
        $user->setSuperAdmin((Boolean) $superadmin);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

        return $user;
    }

Comment: @DonCallisto [read this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Entity/User.php#L23) It won't be supported so it's better to use proper class. I'm still trying to help him, I don't know why did you downvoted :/

Comment: @wattever Is your `VillaPrivee\UserBundle\VillaPriveeUserBundle.php` class overriding `getParent` method?

Comment: @bartek : here is the file content:

    <?php

    namespace VillaPrivee\UserBundle;

    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

    class VillaPriveeUserBundle extends Bundle
    {
    }

Comment: @wattever maybe edit your post and paste your code there

Comment: @wattever I run out of ideas. Maybe try to go step-by-step with [installation and configuration](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) and clear your cache?

Comment: @bartek : been through the whole process twice and cleared the cache every time I could... still no effect
Could this be related to an autoload issue or something?

Comment: Oh by the way : when I try to login via the /login page (even though no user has been created, I'm aware of that), I get this error : "Unrecognized field: usernameCanonical". It seems that none of the User information is recognized

Comment: Ok, do you have `fos_user` in your `config.yml` configured correctly?

Comment: you can try some of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999335/fos-userbundle-unrecognized-field-usernamecanonical)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone gets the same issue as I did, i found out where the problem came from : I'm using a Mac but didn't want to get in trouble using the embedded PHP server. So I decided to use MAMP... Huge mistake!
Everything I tried using my terminal was trying to access default PHP instead of MAMP one...
Basically, I had to remove MAMP and upgrade my Mac PHP so I could use it together with Symfony.
Sorry if I'm not crystal clear, but I don't really understand it all myself...

PS: For those using MAMP, don't be as stupid as I am : your project folder is stored INSIDE your MAMP application folder. So if you trash it, you'll trash all your projects at the same time... Yep, I'm still crying about it!

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue. This video really helped me.
https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/fosuserbundle-ftw

in AppKernel.php

This was my mistake:

```
 $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User()
    );
```

This is the problem **new \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User()**

Follow the video and you will see that you need something like this

```
$bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new \Acme\UserBundle\AcmeUserBundle()
    );
```

Here is the AcmeUserBundle class:

```
// src/Acme/UserBundle/AcmeUserBundle.php
namespace Acme\UserBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

The UserBundle\Entity\User class is just like in the documentation

One last thing that I also saw on the view was the **orm:** entry in the config.yml Notice the **auto_mapping: true**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

Hops this will help someone else